# Вставка и удаление элементов из std::map в цикле

Tags: c++

Можно ли в цикле по `std::map` на каждом шаге совершать несколько удалений и вставок элементов в этот же контейнер? Т.е. будет ли правильно работать следующий код?

```
std::map<int, int> my_map;
for (auto&& it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end();) {
  if (pair.second == 42)
    it = my_map[pair.first].erase(it);
  if (2 + 2 == 4)
    it = my_map.emplace(42, 42).first;
  //...
  if (no_insert_and_no_erase)
    ++it;
}
```

Comment: Ну по идее должен, почему бы ему не работать? Если только скомпилируется.

Comment: @VladD я исхожу из той логики, что при удалении возвращенный итератор может проскочить вставленный на этой итерации элемент

Comment: Ну у вас же сначала удаление?

Comment: @VladD нет, имеется в виду, что порядок произвольный и количество тоже

Comment: Только вот непонятна логика со вставкой: если вставка будет в конец, вы перепрыгнете весь список?

Comment: @VladD нет, такого не должно быть, получается, изменять итератор при вставке не надо

Comment: Всё равно непонятно. Если вставка произойдёт в начало, а итератор уже это самое начало прошёл, что тогда?

Comment: @VladD добавляемые элементы проходить в цикле не надо, только все старые

Comment: Окей, тогда наоборот, если элемент добавится в конец, то итератор до него дошагает. Тоже как-то не очень.

Comment: @VladD то есть это невыполнимо в принципе?

Comment: Ну, не вполне понятно, чего вам хочется. При некоторых условиях оно, возможно, и взлетит, но грань между правильным и неправильным кодом слишком тонкая. Почему бы не добавить элементы потом, после завершения этого цикла?

Comment: @VladD но их же тоже в цикле придется добавлять

Comment: Да, и что? Вы хотите сэкономить наносекунду, нужную на управление циклом?

Comment: @VladD нет, разве там не будут такие же проблемы?

Comment: А какие там проблемы? Когда вы добавляете, вам вовсе не нужно итерировать по вашей `map`. Просто добавьте всё, что нужно.

Comment: @VladD а, точно. Ладно, спасибо, буду делать так, как вы сказали

Answer (score 2):

**pair< iterator, bool> container::emplace (args)** //std::map

**iterator container::emplace (args)** // std::multimap

Для всех контейнеров(ассоциативных и неупорядоченных) операция вставки сохраняет корректность ссылок на существующие элементы. Для ассоциативных контейнеров все итераторы установленные на существующие элементы остаются корректными.

**iterator container::erase(iterator)** (С++11)

При удалении элемента главное не удалить итератор ссылающийся на этот элемент.

```
std::map<std::string, int> coll;
...
for(auto pos = coll.begin(); pos != coll.end(); ++pos)
{
  if(pos->second == value)
    coll.erase(pos); // Ошибка во время выполнения
}
```

В С++11 функция-член erase всегда возвращает значение следующего элемента.

```
std::map<std::string, int> coll;
...
for(auto pos = coll.begin(); pos != coll.end();)
{
  if(pos->second == value)
  {
    pos = coll.erase(pos); // C++11
  }
  else
  {
    ++pos;
  }
}
```

Если вы хотите заменить какой-то ключ элемента коллекции, то для этого существует только одна возможность: необходимо заменить старый элемент новым с тем же значением.

```
template<typename Cont>
bool replaceKey(Cont& c, 
                const typename Cont::key_type& oldKey, 
                const typename Cont::key_type& newKey)
{
typename Cont::iterator pos;
pos = c.find(oldKey);

  if(pos != c.end())
  {
    //Вставка нового элемента
    c.insert( typename Cont::value_type(newKey, pos->second) );
    //Удаляем старый элемент
    c.erase(pos);

    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Для мапы также существует более простой способ:

```
coll["newKey"] = coll["oldKey"];
coll.erase("oldKey");
```